# no route match rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

am trying to add routes to my rails app but everytime i try to load the index page it returns no route match.
my

**product.rb**

```
belongs_to :category
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
 default_scope { where(active: true) }
end
```

and here is my category.rb

```
has_many :products
  extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

and my routes are setup like this

```
    resources :categories
    get '/products/:category_id/:id/', to: 'products#show', as: 'product'
    resources :products
```

in my index page i have it like this

```
<%= link_to product, class: "card" do %>
<div class="product-image">
<%= image_tag product.productpic.url if product.productpic? %>
    </div>

      <div class="product-text">
        <h2 class="product-title"> <%= product.name %></h2>
          <h3 class="product-price">£<%= product.price %></h3>
      </div>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

but when ever i load the page in my broser i get

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>#<Product id: 4, name: "virgin hair", price: #<BigDecimal:7fd0af3ffb10,'0.3E3',9(18)>, created_at: "2016-07-19 12:34:34", updated_at: "2016-07-19 12:41:36", slug: "virgin-hair", productpic: "longhair.jpg", pdescription: "this a brazilian virgin hair", active: true, category_id: 2>, :controller=>"products"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

what am i doing wrong here as i am a novice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing **product** object in place of category_id.
Try this,

```
 :category_id => product.category_id
```

Comment: is this how i should add it? `get '/products/:category_id => product.category_id/:id/', to: 'products#show', as: 'product'`

Comment: Just replace your <%= link_to product, class: "card" do %> with this <%= link_to product(categoty_id: product.category_id, id: product.id), class: "card" do %>

Comment: this breaks and bringa undefined method `product' for

Comment: replace product with product_path(categoty_id: product.category_id, id: product.id)

Comment: after remoing the `as: 'product' `from routes now its returning routes like this instead of the slug name `http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/3?categoty_id=2` while hardcoding this in the browser works `http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/clothing/virgin-hair`

Comment: sorry typo mistake, Just try this <%= link_to product_path(category_id: product.category_id, id: product.id), class: "card" do %>

Comment: it returns the url as `http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/3?category_id=2` instead of `http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/clothing/virgin-hair`

Comment: just replace your ids with slugs

Comment: when i add slug to category id returs undefined method `category_slug'

Comment: I think the routing issue is solved, now just try use your slugs properly and please accept the answer if so.

Comment: this the right answer. change my routes into  ` get '/products/:category_name/:id/', to: 'products#show', as: 'product'` and also `get '/products', to:  'products#index', as: 'product_path'` then in my views have it like `link_to product_path(id: product.slug, category_name: product.category.name)`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called `nested routing`.

And this is how you make it right:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
  resources :products
end
```

in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
...
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = @category.products.find(params[:id])
  end
...
```

and in your view (to link the above controller action):

```
<%= link_to 'Awesome Product!', category_product_path(@category, @product) %>
```

Defining routes like above will let you make paths like this:

`/categories/123/products/1`

**EDIT**

To find a record using the name you could do something like this in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
...
  def show
    @category = Category.find_by!(name: params[:category_id])
    @product = @category.products.find_by!(name: params[:id])
  end
...
```

Comment: well i want to archive something like /products/categoryname/produtcsname i can archive this when i hardcode it in my browser `http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/clothing/virgin-hair` but the routes return as `http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/3?category_id=2` when its dynamic on index page

Comment: Then you're not doing it the rails way, it's the best way to handle routes like I described in the answer. (Plus google loves these paths, helps you indexing better)
To make it search for the name not the id, you can change your controller code. (see edit)

Comment: this rails way as its on rails route guideline `get '/products/:category_id/:id/', to: 'products#show', as: 'product_path'` the only issue am having is to make it work in the views since i can acces it in the browser

Comment: Go to the 2 links I posted.. where do you see such a think as `get '/products/:category_id/:id/', to: 'products#show', as: 'product_path'` ?!

Comment: here `get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'` you can do this for resource routes.

Comment: yes but what you're trying to achieve are NESTED RESOURCES!
see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources What you just posted is the "dumb" way to write: `resources :patients, only: [:show]`

Comment: you still dont understand what am trying to do,  this works fine http://10.0.0.19:3000/products/clothing/virgin-hair only issue am having is to get it work in my views